# Get current doc/template this. _id for use in event in Meteor

Tags: meteor

This is from a Meteor edit page for a Post where I am uploading images associated with the Post.

I need to access the current Post._id in order to add to it's images object. How do I get it from within template events?

```
Template.eventEdit.events({

  ...

  'change .header-file-path': function(e, template) {    
    FS.Utility.eachFile(e, function(file) {
      Images.insert(file, function (err, fileObj) {
        Posts.update({_id: CURRENTPOST._id}, {$push: {images: fileObj._id}});
      });
    });
  }

});
```

I have tried template.data and template.currentData() to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be in the context of your post or find that context. You can use `Template.currentData` http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_currentdata (remember that this is 'Template' and not your 'template' var) it should work if you are in the context of your post. If not you can also try to find it by `Template.parentData()` http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_parentdata it all depends on where your context is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, really appreciate it - I must be missing something big - both  console.log(Template.currentData()); and console.log(Template.parentData()); return null. To clarify it is the Ironrouter _id I'm trying to get at from within the event. My router looks like this "Router.route('/event/:_id/edit', { .. });"

Comment: Actually - you are right, I had something else going on - in my case both Template.currentData()._id and Template.parentData()._id work fine .. thanks!